# Why aren't dependencies generated inside makefiles?

Tags: c++, gcc, makefile, g++

I recently learned how to use Makefiles, and I found out that GCC/G++ generates dependencies for you:

```
$ g++ -MM file.cpp
file.o: file.cpp file.h
```

I then thought that the obvious thing to do would be to use this to generate dependencies directly in the file without creating a dependency file:

```bash
CXX = g++

SRCS = $(wildcard src/*.cpp)
OBJS = $(SRCS:.cpp=.o)
OCT = $(CXX -MM $(SRCS))
OBJDIR = obj
CPPFLAGS = -Wall -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib -lGLEW -lglfw -lGL

.PHONY: all
all: $(OBJS)
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(OBJS) -o output

$(OCT)

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -f obj/*
```

For some reason, I have never seen anyone else do this; they always generate a dependency file. Is there something wrong with this system? In my case yes -- the objects don't go to OBJDIR, they go to they location of the source file. I'm sure this could be fixed though. If anyone knows how I could fix this and why dependency files are usually generated, please let me know.

Comment: Your way (at least partly) compiles the files twice.

Comment: @CarlNorum How? I am only seeing one compilation -- the compilation by $(OCT).

Comment: Yeah, but you need to compile them to object files too, right? Maybe I'm forgetting what `-MM` does.

Comment: OCT implicitly compiles them to object files, and the all target links them. MM prints out dependencies. Look at the example I have at the top.

Comment: Check your make output; are you sure you don't see the compiler invoked twice for Each object file? The OCT line is one, there should be an implicit invocation for each file as well.

Comment: @CarlNorum `-MM` create a list of makefile dependencies for the specific source file. It is generally done as a secondary pass on a source file. It isn't designed to do much besides parse preprocessor stmts for generating the make targets, which are then usually included with `-include` in the project makefile. If what you remember is similar to that, you remembered correctly.

Comment: Yeah, I just double checked the docs. So this method does require at least the preprocessing to run twice. That's what my original comment was getting at.

Comment: It also requires the preprocessing to run on all source files for every make invocation, which is presumably undesirable for those cases where you haven't made any changes that would logically require a rebuild.

Comment: @CarlNorum Yeah, I generally have mine in the same cmd as the actual compile. By that time you've already determine you need to recompile that source file; a good time to update deps, as the out-of-date source file may have modified the `#include` list for that source file. I concur with your assessment.

Comment: Exactly. That's what the `-MD` flag is for. The only problem turns up when you delete a depended-on header, but simply nuking the appropriate dep/object files solves that in short order.

Comment: @CarlNorum What's the MD flag? I can't seem to find the documentation on it.

Comment: Check [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#Preprocessor-Options): "`-MD` can be used to generate a dependency output file as a side-effect of the compilation process"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the first reason people don't do this is that it's not possible to do: if you try to make your suggestion work in real life you'll see that.  Your example, for instance, doesn't do anything at all.  This:

```
OCT = $(CXX -MM $(SRCS))
```

(I assume you mean `$($(CXX) -MM $(SRCS))` but it doesn't matter either way) is putting a reference to the make variable named, literally, `CXX -MM $(SRCS)` into the variable `OCT`: you probably are thinking that it's using the shell command invocation syntax `$(...)` but this is a *makefile*, not a shell script.  So when you write:

```
$(OCT)
```

that tries to look up that make variable, which obviously does not exist, and so this expands to the empty string and nothing at all happens.  If you actually try to test your makefile by touching a header etc. you'll see nothing gets rebuilt.

How can you do this?  You can't do it.  You can change your variable assignment like this:

```
OCT = $(shell $(CXX) -MM $(SRCS))
```

and that will actually run the compiler, which is moving you in the right direction, *but* the results of the shell function will change all newlines to whitespace, so this:

```
$(OCT)
```

will expand to the entire output of the compiler command *on one line*, and since it contains multiple colons you'll get a syntax error.

All you can do is redirect the output of the compiler to a file, and using make's `include` capability to include that file.  But now you're basically back to the scenario [suggested in the GNU make manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Prerequisites.html), except your version is less efficient because, as pointed out in the comments above, you're regenerating *all* the headers for all the source files every time you run make, rather than only regenerating header information for the files that have actually changed.

There are better/more efficient ways to generate headers, such as [the one used by most GNU packages](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/).